# How to pass unicode characters to stdin or in other way WkHtmlToPdf

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

ASP.NET / Mono MVC4 C# application converts html to pdf using WkHtmlToPdf :

```
    public ActionResult WkHtmlToPdf()
    {
        byte[] result = ConvertHtmlToPdf("<html><body>Testöäüõ</body></html>");
        var ms = new MemoryStream(result);
        return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
    }



    static byte[] ConvertHtmlToPdf(string html)
    {
        var p = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                FileName = Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT ?
            @"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe" : "/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
            }
        };

        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "- -";
        p.Start();
        StreamWriter myStreamWriter = p.StandardInput;
        myStreamWriter.Write(html);
        myStreamWriter.Close();
        var buffer = new byte[32768];
        byte[] file;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var read = p.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (read <= 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            file = ms.ToArray();
        }
        p.WaitForExit(60000);
        var returnCode = p.ExitCode;
        p.Close();
        return returnCode == 0 ? file : null;
    }
```

In result pdf file unicode characters from this code does not appear properly:

[image: Unicode not correct]

How to fix this so that unicode data appears properly in pdf file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try specifying the encoding on the command line call to wkhtmltopdf?

```
wkhtmltopdf --encoding utf-8
```

and/or add it to the html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```